# Wrap the_title_attribute in a H2 within a Conditional Tag?

Tags: title, conditional-tags

I have the following that works fine..

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){the_title_attribute();}
```

However, i need the aforementioned title to be wrapped with a h2 tag.

Tried this but it just puts the h2 after the title...

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){echo'<h2>'. the_title_attribute() .'</h2>';}
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you using `the_title_attribute()` rather than `the_title()`?

Comment: To clarify my comment above: `the_title_attribute()` is intended for outputting the Title *specifically formatted* for use in the `title` attribute of an anchor tag; on the other hand, `the_title()` is intended for general output of the Title. For your use case, you could specifically use `get_the_title()`, which returns, rather than echoes, the string.

Answer (score 3):

The `the_title_attribute()` template tag is intended *specifically* for outputting the Title formatted for use in an anchor tag `title` attribute. The `the_title()` and `get_the_title()` template tags are intended for general print/display of the Title.

I would recommend using `get_the_title()`, rather than `the_title_attribute()`. To wit:

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){echo'<h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';}
```

I believe this would be more semantically correct.

Comment: `the_title` has a param to set echo to false, like with `the_title_attribute`...

Comment: ...certainly, but that's also what `get_the_title()` is designed for. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `the_title_attribute` function already echoes, so you can't echo it's value, try this instead.

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){ ?><h2><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></h2><?php }
```

Or alternatively..

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){ echo '<h2>'; the_title_attribute(); echo'</h2>'; }
```

Or alternately:

```
elseif( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'press' ){ echo '<h2>' . the_title_attribute( '', '', false ) . '</h2>'; }
```

Comment: Or you could set `echo` to `false` for `the_title_attribute()`, like such: `the_title_attribute( '', '', false )`, which would allow for echoing the entire, concatenated construct.

Comment: I didn't check the docs... but yes, you could also do that.. :) I wrongly assumed it didn't have support for it(without checking)..